# When did "text" come to be defined as something other than words?

Tags: meaning, history

I think the answer to this question may be in the OED, but I don't have access to the service. I am discussing "texts" using definitions (from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/text?s=t)) like this:

> text: any theme or topic; subject.

and this

> text: anything considered to be a subject for analysis by or as if by methods of literary criticism.

Within the context of cultural anthropology I'm having a discussion with my students  about how the definition of a *text* has expanded over the years to include not just texts comprising words but also visuals (e.g., images in advertisements).

I've come across the latter usage of *text* in certain educational books:

> "Like written texts, visual texts have been carefully constructed by their composers to shape meaning, and to affect and influence the viewer."

Or

> "This resource covers how to write a rhetorical analysis essay of primarily visual texts with a focus on demonstrating the author’s understanding of the rhetorical situation and design principles."

An ngram search for "visual texts" doesn't have many results before the 1960s, and some of the results refer to visual texts in single or double quotes to highlight the non-standard usage.

> "[visual texts](http://books.google.es/books?id=chWcZcYcyeQC&pg=PA49&dq=%22visual%20texts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L-8pUujPNMSr7AbmgYE4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22visual%20texts%22&f=false)"

or

> visual "[texts](http://books.google.es/books?id=CqCMGYRUlv4C&pg=PR10&dq=%22visual%20texts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L-8pUujPNMSr7AbmgYE4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22visual%20texts%22&f=false)"

My question is:

> - Since dictionaries are formally acknowledging that a text need not be comprised of words only, when did the concept of a 'visual text' become a subject of analysis in its own right?" (e.g., the MacIntosh logo of an apple; see http://creativebits.org/interview/interview_rob_janoff_designer_apple_logo)

Comment: I wasn't aware that 'we' do call "the images in an advert a text". I don't understand what you mean by *text* meaning "something other than words".

Comment: @tylerharms:  I hope my editing clarified your questions.  If not, feel free to re-edit.  Certainly with the proliferation of words in combination with images in our highly visual world, the concept of text has to take the visual component very seriously indeed.  That's not to say the visual component was never important; after all, pictographs go back to ancient cave drawings, do they not?  Teachers today who rely strictly on the printed word (whether hard or electronic or both) handicap themselves and their students unnecessarily.  Visual texts are great pedagogical tools--and more!

Comment: By visual texts do you mean, the ability to transmit and obtain information via images? For example, would you consider the Egyptian hieroglyphics "visual text" too? Can the images be accompanied by written text, or do they stand alone? One of the most famous examples of *visual texts* that come to mind is the bayeux tapestry. Am I on track or completely off the mark?

Comment: This just sounds like a special use of the word in a small technical sense (just for cultural anthropologists. Those outside of that community would think it strange. That is, don't use 'visual text' unless you know your audience will appreciate the incongruity or rather the redefinition.

Comment: @Mitch: It's specific usage, to be sure, but text is defined this way now. I'd just like to know when that definition became formal, so that I can talk about the evolution of what we, in a critical setting, label text.

Comment: @rhetorician: That's not exactly what I'm referring to. See my above comment to Mari-Lou A.

Comment: You're talking about symbolism?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: In the context I'm describing, the images--a car, say--are text, regardless of accompanying wordage. Not in the sense that a pictographic language uses images to convey a story, but in the sense that the Apple logo carries with it all kinds of cultural significance that can be unpacked or even read, I suppose. In that sense, we could call the Apple apple a text.

Comment: Yes. In the way that images have culture significance and signify latent meaning, it seems that they qualify as texts under the above definitions.

Comment: I think you ought to include the comment which starts with:**In the context... **in your question. and then hope somebody answers it to start the ball rolling. It may be as Mitch explained, that the use of this expression is technical, restricted, and known to a limited number of people. I do not belong to that number. :)

Comment: I'm with all those who are not familiar with this usage of *text*. I suspect it is an overwhelming majority of English speakers. I don't believe *text* is widely used this way. As others have suggested, this is **at best** technical jargon.

Comment: Well, *text* **is** used to describe a quotation to be discussed. That use is in the OED, but I doubt I'll have enough time to knock up an answer before this question is closed. To use it in the context of an image is a bit odd, though, and it isn't in the OED, which only emphasises the esoteric nature of that use.

Comment: If my opinion is worth anything, @AndrewLeach I think after the OP's edits the question is clearer now. Go on Andy, give it a shot. :)

Comment: @tylerharms:  I think your question might need a little tweaking.  Instead of "Since dictionaries are formally acknowledging that a text need not be based on words, When did the notion of 'text' get separated from the written word?" you might think of "Since dictionaries are formally acknowledging that a text need not be comprised of words only, when did the concept of a 'visual text' (e.g., the MacIntosh logo of an apple; see http://creativebits.org/interview/interview_rob_janoff_designer_apple_logo) become a subject of analysis in its own right?" Again, feel free to edit the edit. Don

Comment: I think your question is much clearer now, and also, unfortunately, I think it is more suitable for a cultural anthropology site. We can help you with when *visual text* was coined probably, but not with when images became the subject of textual analysis.

Comment: @KitFox for once ELU receives an intellectually demanding and challenging question, which I for one am curious to see if anyone else can provide an answer to, and it's on hold?! The OP's question is clearer and basically he's asking for the etymology and more sophisticated evolution of the word, text. Isn't that relevant to the English language? (Please read my comment as someone who is genuinely interested.)

Comment: @KitFox: I see it being a question of cultural anthropology too, but I'm more interested in the standardization of the definition. That's a language usage question to me.

Answer (score 2):

'Text' is commonly used to describe things other than words in fields such as the history of art, literary theory and so on.

According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_(literary_theory))

> In literary theory, a text is any object that can be "read," whether this object is a work of literature, a street sign, an arrangement of buildings on a city block, or styles of clothing. It is a coherent set of signs that transmits some kind of informative message. This set of symbols is considered in terms of the informative message's content, rather than in terms of its physical form or the medium in which it is represented.

I suspect it's only been commonly used this way since the 1960s. Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_theory#Language_and_communication) states:

> From the 1960s and 1970s onward, language, symbolism, text, and meaning came to be seen as the theoretical foundation for the humanities, through the influence of Ludwig Wittgenstein, Ferdinand de Saussure, George Herbert Mead, Noam Chomsky, Hans-Georg Gadamer, Roland Barthes, Jacques Derrida and other thinkers in linguistic and analytic philosophy, structural linguistics, symbolic interactionism, hermeneutics, semiology, linguistically oriented psychoanalysis (Jacques Lacan, Alfred Lorenzer), and deconstruction

Comment: The wikipedia page you link to states that "a text is any object that can be _read_" so pictograms work, a photograph of my grandmother won't.

Comment: @terdon ah, but but note the quotation marks around the word 'read'. In this context 'read' doesn't have the usual meaning. Paintings, symbols, street signs can all be 'read' (ie interpreted, placed in their context, linked to the world around them)

Comment: Postmodern authors often talk about "reading" almost anything. And you can definitely "read" someone's face or body language. If we accept metaphors, there's no limit.

Comment: @TimLymington: Indeed. That's my point.

Comment: I think this usage of text comes out of post-modernism, although the metaphor of reading something visual is who knows how old. I imagine the post-modern sense comes from semiotics, but I haven't been able to find the person who has taken the leap from calling an image a signifier to calling it a text.

Comment: As yours is the only answer, could you put in block quotes an excerpt from Wikipedia to further substantiate the definition of "text" from a "literary theory" viewpoint, please?

Answer (score 2):

It is not only common to refer to any object of interpretation as a text at the collegiate level, it is written into the very course catalog descriptions.  For example, one of the aesthetics courses I took in grad school was called "Reading Texts: Developing Cultural Fluency" and the main text for that course was *Performance Studies: The Interpretation of Aesthetic Texts*.  Certainly this usage dates from at least Hans-Georg Gadamer's *Truth and Method* (1975) and is inferred by Roland Barthes in "The Photographic Message," no. 1, Communications (Paris, 1961). While Barthes wrote that "(t)he photographic image (...) is a message without a code," he did speak of the *reading* the photographic image as parallel with the reading of its caption and title.

So, if I were you, I would likely argue that the 1961 article represents the archetypal--if not originating--use of "text" to refer to non-written objects of interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the Barthes reference. I have it and will look through it for any evidence of text being used for images. I think Ferdinand de Saussure would probably be an earlier example of this understanding of texts. If you have any resources that cite his usage of "visual texts" I'd be interested in them.

Comment: I fear I may not have made myself sufficiently clear: Barthes, himself, does not expressly apply the term "text" to a non-textual object.  He, instead, infers that a non-textual element's message is "read" in a way analogous its (con)textual elements like the title and caption.  So... Barthes actually uses text and image as distinct categories, but his treatment of photographic images places them in the same semiotic tradition.

Comment: So to summarize, Barthes treatment of the topic is archetypal of the approach "image as text" but did not originate the usage you are investigating.